# C++ comparator function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap, comparator

I'm trying to implement a generic heap in C++. In order to make it generic as possible I'm trying to allow the heap to take a comparator to allow different kinds of heap ordering. However I've never used comparators before and I'm running into an issue. Here is the the setup for my heap.

```
template <typename T>
class greater {
public:
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const { return a > b; }
};

template <typename T, typename C = greater<T> >
class heap {
public:
    //constructors
    heap();
    heap(const heap& other);
    heap& operator= (const heap& other);

    //destructor
    ~heap();

    //operations
    void push(const T& datum);
    T& peek() const;
    void pop();

    //status
    bool empty() const { return tree.empty(); }
    int size() const { return tree.size(); }

    //debug
    void print() const;

private:
    std::vector<T> tree;

    //auxilliary functions
    int parent(int index) { return (index - 1) / 2; }
    int left(int index) { return 2 * index; }
    int right(int index) { return 2 * index + 1; }

    void swap(int a, int b) {
        T temp = tree[a];
        tree[a] = tree[b];
        tree[b] = temp;
    }

    void bubble_up(int index);
    void bubble_down(int index);
};
```

But for my implementation of the bubble_up method I get the following Visual Studio Error: 'compare':function does not take 2 arguments | Error Code:C2660
The error references the line of the while loop in the implementation which is shown below.

```
template <typename T, typename C>
void heap<T, C>::bubble_up(int index) {
    C compare;
    int parent_index = parent(index);
    while (compare(tree[parent_index], tree[index]) && parent_index >= 0) {
        swap(parent_index, index);
        index = parent_index;
        parent_index = parent(index);
    }
}
```

I'm sure that I've handled using the comparison function poorly, but I'm struggling to find a clear explanation for why this is wrong from my googling so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The above compiled fine for me as is, no error (vs2017).

Comment: The above compiled fine for me as is too, no error (vs2013). What's your dev env? Are you using g++? If yes, then maybe you should check your g++ or library version.